# Read rest of while loop output

Tags: bash, loops

I want to run a while loop from output I get from MySQL, but my output is being cut off.

Example output I get from MySQL is:

```
123 nfs://192.168.1.100/full/Some.file.1.txt
124 nfs://192.168.1.100/full/A second file 2.txt
```

My loop looks like so:

```
mysql -uuser -ppass queue -ss -e 'select id,path from queue where status = 0' | while read a b c 
do
    echo $a
    echo $b
done
```

The result for $b cuts off after `nfs://192.168.1.100/full/A`.
How can I have it output the whole sentence?

Comment: What do you want to be in variable `c`?

Comment: I don't want or expect anything, its just a force of habit.
I tried it without `c` and now it works! 
Can you add it as an answer (not a comment) so I can mark it as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second filename contains spaces, so that is where the field is cut off.
Since it is the last field of the output, you can just skip field c:

```
mysql -uuser -ppass queue -ss -e 'select id,path from queue where status = 0' | while read a b
do
   echo $a
   echo $b
done
```

The last field in read will have all remaining fields.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you are reading each line into 3 variables using:

```
read a b c
```

And since your input line also contains a whitespace e.g.

```
124 nfs://192.168.1.100/full/A second file 2.txt
```

with the default `IFS` it is setting 3 variables as:

```
a=124
b=nfs://192.168.1.100/full/A
c=second file 2.txt
```

Since `c` is the last parameter in `read` it is reading rest of the line in `c`.

To fix your script you can just do:

```
read a b
```